# GA4 API runReport (v1beta) returns higher sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The number of "sessions" returned from Data API `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/{propertyName}:runReport` seems to be dependent on requested dimensions.

1. When querying this endpoint with just "date" dimension then the number of "sessions" is the same as in the platform.
2. When querying this endpoint with two dimensions, "date" and for example "transactionId" then the number of "sessions" returned from the API is considerably (~1.4x) higher.

What could be the cause of this difference?

Payload for the first query - just a "date" dimension, returns correct data:

```
{"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2023-05-19","endDate":"2023-05-19"}],"dimensions":[{"name":"date"}],"metrics":[{"name":"sessions"}],"currencyCode":"CZK","keepEmptyRows":false,"offset":0,"limit":100000,"returnPropertyQuota":true}
```

Payload for the second query - "date" and "transactionId" dimensions, returns sessions ~1.4x higher than the first query:

```
{"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2023-05-19","endDate":"2023-05-19"}],"dimensions":[{"name":"date"},{"name":"transactionId"}],"metrics":[{"name":"sessions"}],"currencyCode":"CZK","keepEmptyRows":false,"offset":0,"limit":100000,"returnPropertyQuota":true}
```

There is an [(other) row](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13331684?hl=en) in the data, and if sessions from this row are filtered out then the number is roughly correct.